# Automatic versioning of web site projects in Team City

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, versioning, vs-web-site-project

At my current client we have some legacy ASP.Net web site projects. I am in the process of introducing automatic versioning for our builds and was wondering of how to best do this with web site projects in Team City?

I am currently using Team City's %build.number% variable (set through project build template) as the authoritative version number for a build. For any .NET project that produces assemblies it's hassle-free to use "AssemblyInfo Patcher" Build Feature in Team City but this does not work for web site projects since they do not produce assemblies.

So, any suggestions? I am already using Powershell and psake in my builds so creating scripts that use %build.number% is not a problem, it is more a question of how to inject this into the web site project in a "nice" manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I attempted several solutions but ended up with using the version number of a dependent assembly that gets set by Team City during the build. I added a class to the assembly and it looks something like this:

```
public class VersionUtils
{
    private readonly ILog _logger;
```

`public VersionUtils()
    {
        _logger = LogManager.GetLogger("VersionLogger");
    }

    public string GetWebAppVerison()
    {
        string version = "unknown version";

        var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(VersionUtils));
        try
        {
            version = assembly.GetName().Version.ToString();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Warn("Could not find or read version number from " + assembly.GetName(), ex);
        }

        return version;
    }`